# Как заставить webpack не использовать переменные до объявления

Tags: javascript, webpack

В собранном webpack'ом js бандле вижу следующую картину:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "myCustomPolyfill", ({
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _myCustomPolyfill["default"];
  }
}));

...

var _myCustomPolyfill = _interopRequireDefault(__webpack_require__(/*! ./myCustomPolyfill */ "../tools/polyfills/myCustomPolyfill.js"));
```

_myCustomPolyfill используется до фактического объявления. Как заставить webpack так не делать? Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы любая переменная в девелоперском и релизном бандле сначала объявлялась, а потом уже использовалась.

Comment: А в чём смысл? Какую проблему решаете?

Comment: Смысл в том, что я запускаю получившийся код не в браузере или ноде, а в очень специфическом окружении (qt6/qml), которое требует чуть больше строгости в оформлении кода.

Comment: __myCustomPolyfill используется до фактического объявления._ - на самом деле нет. используется внутри функции `get`, которая вызывается, очевидно, после объявления.

Comment: какую ошибку вы получаете в вашем специфическом окружении? потому что вопрос нужно начинать решать именно с этого и конечно с учетом того что вебпак вполне зрелая система генерации и заставить ее работать по другому не возможно, но вероятно возможно избежать тех ошибок которые вы получаете. как написал  @Grundy вызов идет уже после объявления а переменная (var) инициализируется при первом проходе

Comment: @Grundy, да, я это понимаю, а вот компилятор - увы нет.

Comment: @Daniil Loban, qt.qml.compiler: file:qrc:/bundle.js:2040:12 Variable "_myCustomPolyfill" is used before its declaration at 2049:5.

Comment: @posix https://github.com/qmlc/qmlc - этот компилятор? или какая там команда для компиляции? как вариант можно еще рассмотреть кроме вебпака что-нибудь например rollup

Comment: и еще я не совсем понимаю для чего скармливается результат работы вебпака - qml вроде как для разметки интерфейса используется

Comment: @Daniil Loban, под компилятором я имел  в виду V4 (QJSEngine) с JIT компилятором, используемый в Qt/QML (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-hostenvironment.html). Хорошо, попробую поэкспериментировать с Rollup.js. Webpack у меня используется для сборки React с кастомным рендерером на основе react-reconciler (который рендерит qml). То есть вся логика моего приложения написана с помощью такой абстракции как React.